# How to style every odd p element after h2 element occured in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML that is messed and i can not change it, it looks like this:

```
<div>
  <h2>This is a title cat</h2>
  <p>This is a message</p>
  <p>One cat</p>
  <p>Two cat</p>
  <p>Three cat</p>
  <h2>This is a title dog</h2>
  <p>Dog 0</p>
  <p>Dog 1</p>
  <p>Dog 2</p>
  <p>Dog 3</p>
</div>
```

Now i would like to make every odd p that comes after a h2 element bolder.
So i would like this to be in **bold**:

```
This is a message

Two cat

Dog 0

Dog 2
```

How to write a selector in CSS (no jQuery, no JS available) to make those texts bold?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by using the css `~` selector, followed by the `nth-of-type` (alternatively `nth-child`) selector. You can read more about it these selectors on the MDN: [**General Sibling Selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) and [**:nth-of-type**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).

And here's how to achieve what you wanted. Essentially, you're selecting all **odd** `<p>` elements that are **siblings** (*i.e that come after*) an `<h2>` tag.

```css
h2 ~ p:nth-of-type(odd) {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>This is a title cat</h2>
  <p>This is a message</p>
  <p>One cat</p>
  <p>Two cat</p>
  <p>Three cat</p>
  <h2>This is a title dog</h2>
  <p>Dog 0</p>
  <p>Dog 1</p>
  <p>Dog 2</p>
  <p>Dog 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is correct, but it occured that my issue is more specific issue that does not occur in this case. So i've posted followup question with better example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37408891/how-to-bolder-even-p-element-with-offset-after-h-element-in-css

Answer (score 1):

```
h2 ~ p:nth-of-type(2n+1){
font-weight: 600;
}
```

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality up