# How to bolder even p element with offset after h element in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have code like this:

```
<style>
h2 ~ p:nth-of-type(2n+3) {
  font-weight: 600;
}
</style>

<div>
  <h2>Cats</h2>
  <p>Normal cat</p>
  <p>Normal cat</p>
  <p>Weird cat</p>
  <p>Normal cat</p>
  <p>Weird cat</p>
  <p>Normal cat</p>
  <h2>Dogs</h2>
  <p>Normal dog</p>
  <p>Normal dog</p>
  <p>Weird dog</p>
  <p>Normal dog</p>
  <p>Weird dog</p>
  <p>Normal dog</p>
</div>
```

I can not change HTML or use jQuery or JS. I need to use CSS to make weird dogs and cats bolder. But when i display above code not only weird cats and dogs are bolder, but also first normal dog:

[image: Example]

It seems like the CSS matching Cats extends its use to Dogs.

How to set the CSS selector to make only weird cats and dogs bolder?

Comment: The problem is that `:nth-of-type` works across all `p` elements within the parent. The `h2 ~` is only an additional condition and not the defining condition. The first `p` that follows `h2` is the 7th of its type under the `div` parent, it satisfies the 2n+3 selector (2*2 + 3) and is a sibling of an `h2` and so it gets selected.

Comment: you could use `h2 ~ p:nth-of-type(2n+3):not(:nth-of-type(7n))` but it would be strictly dependant on your markup

Comment: You could do it with `div p:nth-of-type(6n+3), div p:nth-of-type(6n+5)` also but that again would be dependant on markup. Will work for this but if you add a Normal Cat just before the Dogs h2 then it will go for a toss.

Comment: If your HTML does not change you can just override the first sibling after `h2`. With something like `h2 + p { font-weight: 300!important; }`

Comment: @tomaszs Any luck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the style for **Normal dog** using `h2 + p:nth-of-type(2n+3)`. Check below.

```css
h2 ~ p:nth-of-type(2n+3) {
  font-weight: 600;
}
h2 + p:nth-of-type(2n+3) {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Cats</h2>
  <p>Normal cat</p>
  <p>Normal cat</p>
  <p>Weird cat</p>
  <p>Normal cat</p>
  <p>Weird cat</p>
  <p>Normal cat</p>
  <h2>Dogs</h2>
  <p>Normal dog</p>
  <p>Normal dog</p>
  <p>Weird dog</p>
  <p>Normal dog</p>
  <p>Weird dog</p>
  <p>Normal dog</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Strictly dependent on the markup being exact same as in question. One extra `p` in between and it will go for a toss.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37408522/2030321), you can do this by using the css `~` selector, followed by the `nth-of-type` (alternatively `nth-child`) selector.

However, this would also select every 7th item, so you have to override that by using the `:not` selector too. You can read more about it these selectors on the MDN: [**General Sibling Selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) and [**:nth-of-type**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) and [**:not**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).

You could use the following, which is a bit flexible:

```
h2 ~ p:nth-of-type(2n+3):not(:nth-of-type(6n+1)){
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

Even though you mention that the markup is static, the above selector will work should you add more "lists" of animals. Obviously, the order of `weird` and `normal` animals cannot change. The weird animal has to be the 3rd and 5th in the order.

For example:

```css
h2 ~ p:nth-of-type(2n+3):not(:nth-of-type(6n+1)) {
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Cats</h2>
  <p>Normal cat</p>
  <p>Normal cat</p>
  <p>Weird cat</p>
  <p>Normal cat</p>
  <p>Weird cat</p>
  <p>Normal cat</p>
  <h2>Dogs</h2>
  <p>Normal dog</p>
  <p>Normal dog</p>
  <p>Weird dog</p>
  <p>Normal dog</p>
  <p>Weird dog</p>
  <p>Normal dog</p>
  <h2>Birds</h2>
  <p>Normal bird</p>
  <p>Normal bird</p>
  <p>Weird bird</p>
  <p>Normal bird</p>
  <p>Weird bird</p>
  <p>Normal bird</p>
  <h2>Monkeys</h2>
  <p>Normal monkey</p>
  <p>Normal monkey</p>
  <p>Weird monkey</p>
  <p>Normal monkey</p>
  <p>Weird monkey</p>
  <p>Normal monkey</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Harry, indeed, but this is unavoidable. I state this in the post.

Comment: Oh yeah, just noticed your edit. I guess you edited it in as I was typing my comment :)